# How to connect to a Linux (Debian) VM from the host (Windows 7) using VNC?

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, vnc, vnc-server

I have a Debian 8 VM using Virtualbox running on a Windows 7.
I've installed TightVNC server on my Debian vm, and UltraVNC on my Windows 7 host, but every ip I try (with the port 5901) returns a "failed to connect to server".

How do I find the correct ip address of the VM in order to connect to its vnc server from the host machine? Is there any other configuration needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter into the configuration of the GUEST host.

**In configuration / Screen / Remote Screen**

check the **enable checkbox**. (take care of port number)

Then, you only need to open a RDC client (just the Remote access of windows), Put the IP of the **HOST** machine (and the port like 10.10.10.10:3389) and you are connected fron Anywhere to the Guest machine.

if you need to use VNC, then  you need to bridge the tap (ethernet) or need to bypass the port to the machine to reach it from the network.

If you need to connect only with VNC from HOST to GUEST, just read the IP of the ethernet interface of the GUEST, and just connect to this IP From the HOST PC.

You can type in a console **IP ADDR** to get the IP of the Debian GUEST.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the first line. Where is the "remote screen configuration"? In my Debian VM? Or my Win 7 host?

Comment: In my Windows host it is already enabled. I have a Windows VM as well and I can access it through remote desktop from the host. But when it comes to the Debian VM there is no way the VNC client can connect to the vnc server in the VM.

Comment: I tried both the ip configured in the virtualbox, the ip that virtualbox gives to the vm (10.0.2.xx) and local host. All using the default vnc post (5901). None works whatsoever.

Comment: 1- In the VBox - Machine configuration, so it can be done only in HOST w7.
2. Where is VNC client and VNC host?

Comment: My VCN server is running on my Debian (guest vm on virtualbox) and the VNC client is running on my Windows 7, which is the host machine. All of this is because I don't like to use a VM through the virtualbox window; it is much better to use a vm by remote accessing it.

Comment: I sugest you use RDC. In Virtualbox, configuration of the guest, go to Screen / Remote Screen / and enable it.
Then, try to connect to the IP of the Debian 10.0.2.xx:3389 (port default) using remote access of windows

Comment: But, if you in Windows runs VNC and connect to 10.0.2.xx:5901, you must to connect to Debian.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked with rdc.